Implementing Dynamic Focus Transitions in a Scrollable Card List Using LazyColumn in jetpack Compose
I am trying to build scrollable cards that holds some data, for the first time I want to focus in the first item by expanding it height and changing it color(see pic1), when he start scrolling I want to shrink the first item and putting the second item in the middle of the screen and focus on it(see pic2), but my code keeps the focus in the top as the video, knowing that the height of  the expanded item will be dynamic depending on content size. Below is my code:


video link
data class ListItem(val text: String)

@Composable
fun MyScreen(items: List<ListItem>) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val layoutInfo = remember { derivedStateOf { listState.layoutInfo } }
    val firstVisibleItemIndex = layoutInfo.value.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull()?.index ?: 0
    val lastVisibleItemIndex = layoutInfo.value.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: 0
    val middleItemIndex = (firstVisibleItemIndex + lastVisibleItemIndex) / 2
    val screenHeightDp = LocalDensity.current.run { LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp }
    val highlightedCardHeightDp = (screenHeightDp * 2 / 3)
    val otherCardHeightDp = (screenHeightDp / 6)

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        state = listState,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listState)
    ) {

        itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
            ListItem(
                item = item,
                isMiddleItem = if (!listState.canScrollBackward) index == 0 else middleItemIndex == index,
                highlightedCardHeightDp,
                otherCardHeightDp
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListItem(
    item: ListItem,
    isMiddleItem: Boolean,
    highlightedCardHeightDp: Dp,
    otherCardHeightDp: Dp
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(if (isMiddleItem) highlightedCardHeightDp else otherCardHeightDp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
            .border(1.dp, if (isMiddleItem) Color.Blue else Color.Gray)
            .animateContentSize(
                tween(
                    durationMillis = 600,
                    delayMillis = 400,
                )
            ),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors().copy(
            contentColor = Color.White,
            containerColor = if (isMiddleItem) Color.Blue else Color.Gray
        ),
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .padding(8.dp),
            text = item.text,
            fontSize = if (isMiddleItem) 38.sp else 18.sp,
        )
    }
}

Requirements:

The initial state should have the first card expanded and highlighted.
As the user scrolls, the cards should shrink, and the currently focused card should be centered and highlighted dynamically.
The height of the highlighted item should be dynamic based on the content.

